# An error occurred (426) when calling the ListTables operation: Upgrade Required

Tags: docker, http, amazon-dynamodb-local

At work we use the `amazon/dynamodb-local` docker for local DynamoDb.

However when I run `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region local`

I get:

> An error occurred (426) when calling the ListTables operation: Upgrade Required

whereas it works for my colleague (and same for other operations)

My colleague and I have the same `docker images` and the same `aws --version`... Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved this exact issue myself - some other process (Loom actually) was doing something on the port in question (8000). Killing that got rid of this error.

Assuming you're on a Mac run `lsof -i :8000` (replace 8000 with whatever port you're using) to see what might be conflicting.

Comment: it was Loom! now we know, thanks

Comment: Ha no way! Silly Loom.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by restarting the computer. We don't know yet exactly what happens but some process that was started at the start of the computer would cause failures, will update the question when found which one exactly